# Output file sizes different between NAnt and VS/MSBuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nant

I am using NAnt for my build process, outputting a DLL.

Everything compiles fine. But when I compare the output from NAnt vs VS/MSBuild, I get a size difference of 2MB between the files.

I have included all the same references (even going as far as to explicitly set the System references in the build file).

When I load the application, if I use the NAnt DLL, I get a runtime error. But with the VS version of the DLL, everything runs smoothly.

I would appreciate any help anyone can lend, or if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Run both NAnt and MSBuild with verbose switches on (`-verbose` / `/v:diag`), compare the exact command line call to `csc.exe` they use. Also, I'm kind of worried by the fact that your assembly is large enough that a 2MB size difference is even possible.

Comment: Thanks, skolima.  See my follow up post for what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and just wanted to add the resolution in case anyone else hits a similar issue.
There was an XML file within the project that I was not referencing properly via my build file.
I was including it in the reference node of the csc tag rather then in a resources node. fixing this fixed my issue.